# How to remove numbers in Python Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is My DataFrame

```
                                                 col
0  1. This is the most beautiful place in the world.
1  2. This man has more skills to show in cricket...
2  3. That’s exactly I wanted to become, a highes...
3  4. We are deeply finanicaial to co-creating sc...
4      5. Company proximate to our operations liv...
5     6. Dot chain management is key to the opera...
6  7. Diversity within our workforce is of paramo...
7  8. The Indian scrap industry is highly fragmen...
8       9. Steel has progressively met the challe...
```

Output should come like below format:

```
                                                 col
0     This is the most beautiful place in the world.
1  This man has more skills to show in cricket th...
2  That’s exactly I wanted to become, a highest r...
3   We are deeply finanicaial to co-creating scal...
4         Company proximate to our operations liv...
5        Dot chain management is key to the opera...
6     Diversity within our workforce is of paramo...
7     The Indian scrap industry is highly fragmen...
8          Steel has progressively met the challe...
```

Comment: Please don't add data or code as pictures. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex` - `^` is for start of string, `\d+` is for one or more digits, `\.` is escaped `.` and `\s+` is for one or more whitespaces:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'^\d+\.\s+','')
```

If maximal number is `9` remove first 3 values by position with indexing:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str[3:]
```

---

```
print (df)
                                                 col
0     This is the most beautiful place in the world.
1  This man has more skills to show in cricket th...
2  That’s exactly I wanted to become, a highest r...
3   We are deeply finanicaial to co-creating scal...
4         Company proximate to our operations liv...
5        Dot chain management is key to the opera...
6     Diversity within our workforce is of paramo...
7     The Indian scrap industry is highly fragmen...
8          Steel has progressively met the challe...
```